# onPageFinished() sometimes doesn't get called

Tags: android, android-webview, webviewclient

I have a custom implementation of `WebViewClient` that overrides `onPageFinished()`, where I swap my loading view with the `WebView`. Sometimes everything works great, but other times `onPageFinished()` doesn't get called at all. It's completely random.

`onPageStarted()` always gets called.

```
public class LoaderWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    private final TableLayout swapTableLayout;

    public LoaderWebViewClient(TableLayout swapTableLayout) {
        this.swapTableLayout = swapTableLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon); 
    }

    // Sometimes doesn't get called
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

        swapTableLayout.removeAllViews();
        swapTableLayout.addView(view);

        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }
}
```

I am instantiating a `WebView` from a custom class:

```
WebView webView = new WebView(context);

WebViewClient webViewClient = new LoaderWebViewClient(swapTableLayout);
webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);

webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.setOverScrollMode(WebView.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
webView.loadUrl(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem. In `onPageFinished()` I am removing all the views from the layout inside which the `WebView` itself would reside (as seen in the next line).

And that somehow disrupts the loading of the `WebView`. I have just replaced removing and reinserting views with hiding and showing them (they are always inflated in the layout) and everything seems to work fine.